# Nvd3 charts - Passing key value as unicode string

Tags: python, django, unicode, nvd3.js

I'm doing a project with Django and I'm using `nvd3` charts to render some data. The version I'm using is:

```
<script src="http://nvd3.org/lib/d3.v2.js" type="text/javascript\"></script>
<script src="http://nvd3.org/nv.d3.js" type="text/javascript\"></script>
```

I don't have any troubles with the charts but the axis key. This is the part where I initialize the data list:

```
data = [{
            'color': 'green',
                'values': [],
                'key': 'whatever',
                'yAxis': '1'
        }, ];
```

If I initialize the data like this I don't get any error and the chart is rendered succesfully, but If I'm using a word with accent like "whatéver" in the template the axis key is render as "whatÃ©ver". My first option was adding `unicode` to the string something like:

```
data = [{
            'color': 'green',
                'values': [],
                'key': u'whatéver',
                'yAxis': '1'
        }, ];
```

But when I add the `u` to the string I get this error on browser console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

and the chart is not rendered

Any suggestions ? I've checked nvd3 documentation but couldn't find any related with this.

**Edit:** I've tried to use HTML encoding for the char "é" like:

```
data = [{
            'color': 'green',
                'values': [],
                'key': u'what&egrave;ver',
                'yAxis': '1'
        }, ];
```

Didn't work out

Comment: At the top of your .py file:
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: I already has that on my code

Comment: Couldn't know I don't have the full output of your code. Are you passing the data to an ajax request? or are you rendering that in the template?

Comment: You're right, sorry, but I didn't want to put all the code because it'll be a lot of it and the majority part of it is useless. I'm rendering to the template, without AJAX. Anyway I found one solution by passing the "é" char encoded for JavaScript using "\351" like `what\351ver`

Comment: Use the python json encoder:
`import json`
`json.dumps(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one solution by passing the variable to the template encoded for JavaScript.

I want to render `whatéver` so I pass to the template `what\351ver`

I'm not sure if this is the only solution or there is another one better than this

I didn't choose my answer as correct in case that somebody knows another option better than this one

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to render Arabic.  It works fine.

```java
private String escapeJava(String src) {
    final CharsetEncoder asciiEncoder = Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder();
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (final Character character : src.toCharArray()) {
        if (asciiEncoder.canEncode(character)) {
            result.append(character);
        } else {
            result.append("\\u");
            result.append(Integer.toHexString(0x10000 | character).substring(1).toUpperCase());
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).